# how to pass an error message from django admin filter to change list

Tags: django, django-admin

On my change list admin page, I made a custom filter.
I want to be able to send an error/warning message back to the user when a choice is wrong.
(I know that filter choices by default are never wrong but I've converted the select drop down into a text input and therefore some values could be invalid)

Any idea how I can send an error message from a filter?
Here is what I tried:

```
#filter.py
class MyFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = ugettext_lazy('Score')
    parameter_name = 'Score'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [('0.9', 's>=0.9')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        try:
            something
        except Exception as ex:
            request.error_msg = 'xxx'
        return queryset


# admin.py
@admin.register(SomeModel)
class MyAdmin(CustomAdmin):
    list_filter = (MyFilter,)
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if hasattr(request, 'error_msg'):
            print request.error_msg
```

to send "error_msg" to the change_list admin template and display it.
Another idea is to redirect but I don't think it's possible from the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/) could be used to display the error to the user such as:

```
from django.contrib import messages


class MyFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = ugettext_lazy('Score')
    parameter_name = 'Score'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [('0.9', 's>=0.9')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        try:
            something
        except Exception as ex:
            messages.error(request, '<error string>')
        return queryset
```